# Use Custom script for authenticating users for Jenkins from my application database

Tags: authentication, jenkins, groovy

I am having a web application that has a MySQL Database which contains the user and the passwords. I have a Jenkins setup which does some job execution.

When I explore how to make Jenkins use the user name and password from my database, it looks like I can use a custom authentication method to validate the user and allow me to login. Example: https://serverfault.com/questions/839008/jenkins-auth-plugin-where-to-store-the-script-and-how-to-pass-parameters

When I try to search on how to talk to my database from within the groovy script, I find no help documentation or sample. I am new to Jenkins and groovy. I am not sure if I need to write a groovy script to authenticate a user or if I need to create a new security realm and write a new java plugin to perform the authentication as per the sample referred here: https://github.com/mig82/jenkins-security-example

Kindly help me with the best practice along with a link to documentation or sample code.

**EDIT**
I have tried with the below piece of groovy script in jenkins, but it is still failing in the authentication flow.

```
def env = System.getenv()
def username = env['U']
def password = env['P']
println "Authenticating user $username"
if (authenticate(username, password)) {
 System.exit 0
} else {
 System.exit 1
}
def authenticate(def username, def password) {
 def userIsAuthenticated = true
 // Authentication logic goes here
 return userIsAuthenticated
}
```

I am not getting any error in the log file and the user is also not getting logged in to the system.

Answer (score 0):

The plug-in was obsolete and not working. Hence, I built my own plug-in for Jenkins so that I handle the authentication better.

Detailed steps of implementation: https://dsaravanan.wordpress.com/2019/12/25/creating-a-new-security-realm-plugin-for-jenkins/

Source Code: https://github.com/d-saravanan/jenkins-security-realm-plugin